# How to parse JSP Pages into a XML file?

Tags: java, jsp, jsoup, saxparser

I am trying to convert a JSP page document into a XML file.I have been using jsoup and very well reading the whole content except server tags, but I can't understand how can the whole HTML be converted to XML tags. I mean how can I fetch data line by line?

My Code:

```
File Html=new File("genXML.jsp");
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(Html,"UTF-8","http://www.example.com");
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Any assistance would be great

Comment: Why would you want to fetch it line-by-line? Once you read it in if you dump it out again it should be cleaned up, no?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not the same to convert JSP to XML with converting HTML to XML. I suppose you want to translate the HTML generated from a JSP to XML. Second of all, you don't want to do this line by line. An HTML block usually does not begin and ends in a line.

Anyway, you could use a tool like [tagsoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to convert HTML code to XHTML. XHTML is actually XML. Tagsoup can be called to make the translation. I don't know if it has a usefule API, but at least it could be called from your code as an external process using something like this:

```
Process tr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "..." } );
```

Then if you want to transform it to a target XML schema, you could apply an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) transformation using a tool like ones found online (check [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) and [this](http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php)). You could apply the XSLT transformation programmatically using [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html).

Hope I helped!

Comment: Check my edited answer. I did not find an API, but I suppose you could use the tools I suggest programmatically...

Comment: I was going through the website http://jsoup.org/ and found a way to convert html rather than Jsp. but can't find how to use siblingElements,nextElementSibling,firstElementSibling etc.

Comment: I was going through the website http://jsoup.org/ and found a way to convert html rather than Jsp. but can't find how to use siblingElements, nextElementSibling, firstElementSibling etc.
I am novice about jsoup, please give me the code to parse & convert html file to xml file.
I can only read the whole document html successfully,but don't know how to do the whole thing in code.